# Implicit user defined conversion not working because operator and conversion constructor are unrecognized when compiling C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have included the minimal amount of code to replicate this issue.

I would like it if I could assign a Furlong object to a Metric object and vice versa but instead the compiler gives me this error:

> no operator "=" matches these operands

Header file:

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H_
#define DISTANCE_H_

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

//const to facilitate conversions between the two classes

const double FEET_IN_METERS = 0.3048;
const double FURLONG_TO_FEET = 660;

class Furlong;
class Metric;

class Furlong {
public:

    Furlong(int fur = 0, int yar = 0, int fee = 0.0);

    // Copy Constructor.

    Furlong( const Furlong& rhs );

    // Destructor.

    ~Furlong(void);

    // Assignment operator=.
    Furlong&    operator=( Furlong& rhs);

    int furlong;
    int yards;
    double feet;

};

class Metric {

public:
Metric(int kilo = 0, double mete = 0.0);

Metric (const Metric& rhs);

~Metric(void);

Metric& operator=(Metric& rhs);

Metric (Furlong& f);

operator Furlong();

int kilometers;
double meters;
};

#endif
```

Class Definition file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Distances.h"

//FURLONG CLASS DEFINITIONS

//Constructor

Furlong::Furlong(int fur, int yar, int fee) {
    furlong = fur;
    yards = yar;
    feet = fee;
}

// Copy Constructor.

Furlong::Furlong( const Furlong& rhs ) {
    furlong = rhs.furlong;
    yards = rhs.yards;
    feet = rhs.feet;
}

    // Destructor.

Furlong::~Furlong(void) {

}

    // Assignment operator=.

Furlong& Furlong::operator=( Furlong& rhs) {

    furlong = rhs.furlong;
    yards = rhs.yards;
    feet = rhs.feet;

    return *this;

}
//METRIC CLASS DEFINITONS


Metric::Metric(int kilo, double mete) {
    kilometers = kilo;
    meters = mete;
}
Metric::Metric(const Metric& rhs) {

    kilometers = rhs.kilometers;
    meters     = rhs. meters;
}

Metric::~Metric(void) {

}

Metric& Metric::operator=(Metric& rhs) {
    kilometers = rhs.kilometers;
    meters     = rhs.meters;

    return *this;
}

// conversion constructor

Metric::Metric (Furlong& f) {
 kilometers = 3;
 meters = 2.0;
}

//conversion operator

Metric::operator Furlong() {
    return Furlong(1, 2, 3.0);
}
```

Main file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Distances.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {
    Furlong one(1,2,3.0); 
    Furlong three(4,5,6.0);
    Metric two(7,8.0);
    Metric four(9, 10.0);

    one = two;
    four = three;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like object two to be converted to type Furlong then assigned to object one. In addition, object three should be converted to type Metric then assigned to object four

Comment: While the full definition of your classes isn't needed, it would be helpful if the reduced definitions were actually c++. I'm pretty sure every non-whitespace line contains an error.

Comment: Your really going to have to provide a [mcve] along with the errors/how it does not work.

Comment: When you say they don't work what do you mean?  Do they compile successfully?  If not, what are the exact errors you are getting?

Comment: You need to add `B &operator =()(const A &a)` to make `to_build = already_made;` compile. You only defined constructors and conversions, but forgot the assignment operator that you are trying to use.

Comment: @nwp If `B` has `B &operator =()(const B &b)` that should work as `A` can be converted to `B`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think both `class A{` and `class B{`  are (potentially correct).  Otherwise, yes, I agree.

Comment: Voting to close as without a [mcve], the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @MartinBonner `Class` with a capital C is incorrect.

Comment: **D'oh!**   With luck, that will be the stupidest thing I say this month.  I've been using C++ for more than 20 years.  One of these days I might get the hang of it....

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to make the conversion explicit for the compiler to find the path:

```
one =  (Furlong) two;
four = (Metric) three;
```

Comment: I edited the comment according to the stated guidelines in case you needed that. Do I need to add that assignment operator to my class?

Comment: @AndrewKatson: I've changed my answer after your edit

Comment: What is the reason in my code that makes conversions work only when they are explicit?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, believe it or not, is merely a lack of `const` correctness.

```
class Furlong
{
public:
    // ...

    // Assignment operator=.
    Furlong&    operator=( Furlong& rhs);

    // ...    
};

class Metric 
{

public:
    // ...

    Metric& operator=(Metric& rhs);

    // ...
};
```

When you attempt to assign a `Furlong` to a `Metric`, here's what happens:

1. There is no `Metric::operator=()` which takes a `Furlong`, or which takes a `[cv] Furlong&`.
2. The compiler determines whether an implicit conversion is possible.  In this case, you provided constructor `Metric (Furlong& f)`, which can be used.
3. The compiler calls this constructor, creating a temporary `Metric`, which is then used to call `Metric& Metric::operator=(Metric&)`.
4. Since `Metric::operator=()`'s parameter is non-`const`, and doesn't take an rvalue reference, it cannot bind to temporary objects.  As no other potential conversions are available, the compiler thus emits an error.

Similarly, when attempting to assign a `Metric` to a `Furlong`, `Metric::operator Furlong()` is used to create a temporary `Furlong`, but `Furlong::operator=()` is unable to accept temporaries as arguments, making conversion impossible.

---

Thus, the solution is simple: Since neither `operator=()` modifies `rhs`, we take it by `const` reference.

```
class Furlong
{
public:
    // ...

    // Assignment operator=.
    Furlong&    operator=(const Furlong& rhs);

    // ...    
};

class Metric 
{

public:
    // ...

    Metric& operator=(const Metric& rhs);

    // ...
};

Furlong& Furlong::operator=(const Furlong& rhs)
{
    // ...
}

Metric& Metric::operator=(const Metric& rhs)
{
    // ...
}
```

This allows `rhs` to bind to temporary objects, such as the `Furlong` generated by `Metric::operator Furlong()` and the `Metric` generated by `Metric(Furlong&)`.  [The code will then compile successfully](http://ideone.com/MxwoLU).

Comment: This isn't directly related, but I would also suggest: 1) **_NEVER_** put a `using` directive (and especially not `using namespace std;`) in a header, because it can inadvertently break any code that uses that header.  If any function defined in the header need members of the standard namespace, either fully qualify the members' names, or put your `using` inside that function.  (It's safer to put `using` directives in source files, but that can still cause trouble because of just how many common names are used by the standard library.)

Comment: 2) If you only need standard library I/O type declarations in the header (such as when you have pointers/references to those types), use [`<iosfwd>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) instead of `<iostream>`; it merely declares the types, and typically results in faster compilation times.  If you need to use the standard output objects themselves in the header (like `cout`), or need to actually _define_ variables of any of the I/O types (like an `fstream`), then you still need to use the appropriate header (e.g., `<iostream>` for `cout`, or `<fstream>` for `fstream`).

Comment: 3) `Metric (Furlong& f)` should take its parameter by `const` reference, both to indicate that it won't be modified, and to allow it to bind to temporaries.  If you change this, remember to change both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: 4) `Metric::operator Furlong()` should be marked as `const`, since it doesn't modify the `Metric`: `operator Furlong() const`.  Again, if you change this, remember to change both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: 5) Since you're manually defining copy constructors, you might also want to look into move constructors (`Furlong(Furlong&&)` and `Metric(Metric&&)`) and move assignment operators (`Furlong& Furlong::operator=(Furlong&&)` and `Metric& Metric::operator=(Metric&&)`), and into "smart" assignment operators (`Furlong& Furlong::operator=(Furlong)` and `Metric& Metric::operator=(Metric)`, which take their parameter by value, using either the copy constructor or move constructor to create it depending on the situation).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more information about why not to use `using namespace std;` in a header, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/5386374) for more information about move semantics.